# Spatial Autocorrelation tool vs. Incremental Spatial Autocorrelation

Tags: spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics

When you run the Spatial Autocorrelation (Monrans I) tool, you have the option of setting 'Conceptualization of Spatial Relationships'.  This option isn't available for the Incremental Spatial Autocorrelation tool.  Aren't these two tools doing the same thing, except one is a one-time process and the other adding defined distance increments for a number of cases?  If so, what is the 'Conceptualization of Spatial Relationships' being used in the Incremental tool?

Comment: I'm assuming you are running ArcGIS? If so, what version?  If not, please share what software/library you are using.

Comment: I am using ArcMaP 10.2.2